# no electrical power to outlet

Tags: wiring

There is a gcfi in both bathrooms but I only have power to the second one. I believe they each provide power to the bathrooms and also to outlets on the front and back of the house. The house is about 40 years old and has NEVER had power to the front gcfi and front outside outlet. Of course they have wires but I really don't think it is connected in the attic. I do have one of those devices that plug into the outlet to be detected in the breaker box, but nothing shows up in the breaker box, either light or signal. I am now too old and creepy to be climbing around in the attic. Does anyone have any ideas? An electrician from church tried to help, but did not want to go into the attic, having had bad experiences from a previous fall. I do not blame him. I really think it is missing a connection. I would appreciate any suggestions. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the most useful thing you can do is to get a young volunteer from church who is willing to crawl into the attic while the electrician volunteer stands below the hatch or whatever. The electrician tells the crawler what to do and the crawler tells the electrician what the crawler sees.

The protocol for reducing the hazard of this procedure is patience. No matter how much they yell at each other, the crawler must think before each step. If anybody feels unsafe at any time, everybody stops and you call a professional.